# PIp install from git repo inside docker build with github actions

Tags: docker, pip, github-actions

I'm working on segregation of common modules into dedicated repositories for our github organization. Use pip install from git repo in `Dockerfile` to install shared modules developed inside the organization

```
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

where git repo dependency referenced like

```
git+https://github.com/org/repo.git@master
```

The faced issue is that I can't make `pip3 install` to authenticate against organisation private repository when running as github action with `pip3 install` inside `Dockerfile`. I want to avoid creating private access token (PAT) for one of the dev as want to be user-agnostic and don't maintain tokens for leaving team members. Tried to use `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` but with deeper reading realized that the token has access to repository where github action is initiated ([link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#about-the-github_token-secret))

> The token's permissions are limited to the repository that contains your workflow

Is there a way to make `pip3 install` working in github actions without PAT?

Error getting in one of many iterations:

```
Collecting git+https://****@github.com/org/repo.git@master (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Cloning https://****@github.com/org/repo.git (to revision master) to /tmp/pip-req-build-mnge3zvd
  Running command git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/org/repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-mnge3zvd
  fatal: could not read Password for 'https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com': No such device or address
WARNING: Discarding git+https://****@github.com/org/repo.git@master. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/org/repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-mnge3zvd Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/org/repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-mnge3zvd Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: There is no magic in `pip install` from a git repo; `pip` just runs `git clone`. So forget about `pip install`, configure your access for `git clone`. You have 2 ways: PAT for HTTPS or ssh keypair(s) for SSH.

Comment: I was able to configure access with PAT inside `docker build` but I'd like to avoid using PAT of system account as it's clunky. I was thinking that there should be a way to clone another private repo of an organization inside GitHub actions without additional tokens

Comment: Nop, there is no. PATs for HTTPS or ssh keypair(s) for SSH.

Comment: Thx @phd a lot was very frustrated that there's no any GitHub Action mechanism which can do checkout seamlessly from another org repo. Ended up with service account on github :(

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you using ssh like this:

In your dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh,id=default pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In your requirements.txt, change to

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/org/repo.git@master
```

Prepare a ssh private key associated with your github account in the repo Settings/Actions/Secrets, with name `SSH_KEY` (It would be better using a dedicate ssh key)

In your action defining yaml, create a step

```
- name: Prepare Key
  uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.4
  with:
    ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
```

This will export an env variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` for later use

Next action step, use the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

```
- name: Build and push
    id: docker_build
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      ssh: |
        default=${{ env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }}
```

reference: https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent#using-the-dockerbuild-push-action-action

Comment: If you found "Host key verification failed" error, you should add `RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 /root/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts` in your Dockerfile